# How can I install php7.1 using brew in 2020

Tags: php, homebrew

I refered to some tutorials in google, but they do not work, I guess those methods are outdated.

eg https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/installing-php71-with-homebrew/

I got error when I run "brew install php@7.1"

macOS Catalina 10.15.4

```
executed
brew install

brew tap
caskroom/cask
homebrew/bundle
homebrew/cask
homebrew/core
homebrew/services
mongodb/brew

brew -v
Homebrew 2.2.12
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 53ccd; last commit 2020-04-08)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 322a2; last commit 2020-04-08)

brew install php@7.1
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Error: No available formula with the name "php@7.1" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Up until the end of March 2018, all PHP related brews were handled by `Homebrew/php` tab, but that has been deprecated, so now we use what's available in the `Homebrew/core` package. This should be a better maintained, but is a much less complete, set of packages.

**PHP 5.6**, **PHP 7.0**, and **PHP 7.1** have been deprecated and removed from Brew [because they are out of support](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), and while it's **not recommended for production**, there are legitimate reasons to test these unsupported versions in a development environment.

Remember only **PHP 7.2 through 7.4** are officially supported by Brew so if you want to install **PHP 5.6**, **PHP 7.0**, or **PHP 7.1** you will need to add this tap:

```
$ brew tap shivammathur/php
```

[Reference here](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php)

Comment: 2021 update: The homebrew-deprecated repo has been… deprecated. Use [shivammathur/php](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php) instead for legacy PHP installs.

Answer (score 4):

PHP@7.1 is deprecated https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php.

So try to install with other repo

```
brew install openldap libiconv
brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
brew install php@7.1
```

https://devhoi.com/threads/install-brew-deprecated-php-version-php-7-1-5-6-7-0-on-brew-macos.25/